# CK Editor - data loss

Tags: ckeditor, outsystems

I have embedded a CKEditor in my application, which I have developed using OutSystems. Whenever I enter some data into the CKEditor and press 'OK' the data is saved, but when I open the CKEditor again for editing then the previously entered data is cleared somehow.

This is against the normal functionality. The user does not wants this data loss.

Any hints ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the CKEditor component has that bug, so this sounds like an application logic problem.

Are you sure you are:

1. Properly saving the Variable bound to the Input that CKEditor is
   overlaying to a persistent place (DB, session variable etc) inside
   the screen Submit action?
2. Loading **that** same Variable with **that** persisted value inside the
   screen Preparation action? (when you come back to edit)

Miguel

Comment: Miguel Melo - Thanks for the loophole, the first part of your answer was right. It works now.